# AsyncTask only works on debug?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Something odd is happening. I have an `AsyncTask` running so that I don't fetch DB data on the UI `Thread`. Here's my task:

#### ProductListActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        new QueryProductsTask(this).execute();
    }
}

public void populateProductList(Cursor products) {
    ProductListAdapter productListAdapter =
            new ProductListAdapter(this, R.layout.product_list_row, products);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(productListAdapter);
}
```

#### QueryProductsTask.java:

```
protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
    Log.v("BagIt.AsyncTask", "doInBackground running");
    // Fetches info from database:
    return new Products(activity.getBaseContext()).select(null, null, null, null);
}

protected void onPostExecute(Cursor c) {
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
    Log.v("BagIt.AsyncTask", "onPostExecute running");
    // Populates ListView through a custom adapter
    activity.populateProductList(c);
}
```

This code **works** when I'm in debug mode. There's no fault with the `Adapter`, or the Db class, as far as I'm aware for now. But when I open the app on my phone, or hit "Run" and not "Debug", it doesn't work. Even if I'm on debug without any breakpoints, it runs, but not outside debug mode.

Here's my logcat:

#### Debug Mode

```
10-21 23:35:05.988  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit W/Xposed﹕ Package name for /data/app/com.ugglynoodle.overflowmod-1.apk had to be retrieved via parser
10-21 23:35:06.258  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.chenasraf.bagit is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
10-21 23:35:06.328  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
10-21 23:35:06.328  15665-15671/com.chenasraf.bagit I/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger is active
10-21 23:35:06.528  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
10-21 23:35:06.528  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
10-21 23:35:06.728  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
10-21 23:35:06.929  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
10-21 23:35:07.129  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
10-21 23:35:07.329  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
10-21 23:35:07.529  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
10-21 23:35:07.729  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
10-21 23:35:07.930  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
10-21 23:35:08.130  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
10-21 23:35:08.330  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1400)
10-21 23:35:08.510  15665-15847/com.chenasraf.bagit V/BagIt.AsyncTask﹕ doInBackground running
10-21 23:35:08.630  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
10-21 23:35:08.731  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
10-21 23:35:08.881  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit V/BagIt.AsyncTask﹕ onPostExecute running
10-21 23:35:09.101  15665-15665/com.chenasraf.bagit W/InputMethodManager﹕ Ignoring onBind: cur seq=4640, given seq=4639
```

As you can see the `Log.v()`s are working properly (last few lines)

#### Run Mode

```
10-21 23:30:29.545  15022-15022/com.chenasraf.bagit W/Xposed﹕ Package name for /data/app/com.ugglynoodle.overflowmod-1.apk had to be retrieved via parser
10-21 23:30:29.585  15022-15043/com.chenasraf.bagit I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
10-21 23:30:29.625  15022-15022/com.chenasraf.bagit I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
10-21 23:30:29.655  15022-15022/com.chenasraf.bagit D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: remove `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();`

Comment: I thought it only lets me debug since it's a synchronous task. Why would it make it HAVE to wait for debugger or not run at all?

Comment: Because it's meant for debugging purposes only. And it's asynchronous not "a synchronous"...opposites.

Comment: typo :P sorry. thanks for the reply I'll accept your answer as soon as the time makes it possible

Comment: Ok, thought it might have been an accident but wanted to make sure you understood

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#waitForDebugger())

> Wait until a debugger attaches.

Removing that line will allow it to run when no debugger is attached.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is explicitly waiting for a debugger to attach. Since you are not running your code in debug mode, `waitForDebugger()` never returns.

[The documentation for `waitForDebugger()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#waitForDebugger()) reads:

> Wait until a debugger attaches. As soon as the debugger attaches, this returns

Simply put, remove that logic. Starting your app in debug mode will wait for the debugger to attach automatically.

Answer (score 1):

remove it or add this if block that will wait and log if you are running in debug mode.

```
protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG){
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
        Log.v("BagIt.AsyncTask", "doInBackground running");
    }
    // Fetches info from database:
    return new Products(activity.getBaseContext()).select(null, null, null, null);
}

protected void onPostExecute(Cursor c) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG){
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
        Log.v("BagIt.AsyncTask", "onPostExecute running");
    }
    // Populates ListView through a custom adapter
    activity.populateProductList(c);
}
```

You will need to add an import statement to your class, BuildConfig should have the same package name as your app or library module

Comment: I'd also advise against using `BuildConfig.DEBUG` as it's inherently broken, and prefer defining your own DEBUG parameter in Gradle.

Comment: How would I go about defining the debug parameter in Gradle and being able to access it in the code?